# WOPI viewing and editing error : 'Keyset does not exist'

Tags: sha256, yammer, pfx, ms-wopi

I'm trying to implement a wopi on our site (our domain is already added to wopi). I can view and edit in first load. But upon clicking the back button and view again or edit I got this error.

[image]

Any idea what causes the issue.

Github: https://github.com/apulliam/WOPIFramework

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same error when implementing WOPI. Unfortunately don't recall the exact reason for it, but as far as I remember, this may be a permission issue (the IIS process can't read the certificate used for the app. Just adjust the permission for the certificates using the Certificates snap-in in the MMC console). To verify that is the problem, you could tell the app to consume the certificate from a PFX (physical) file rather than from the store.

Answer (score 0):

Back button problems are frequently caused by a lack of (or incorrect) wd* parameter implementation.

> Office Online will sometimes pass additional query string parameters to your host page. These query string parameters are of the form wd*. When you receive these query string parameters on your host page URLs, you must pass them, unchanged, to the Office Online iframe.
>
> In addition, if the replaceState method from the HTML5 History API is available in the user’s browser, you should remove the following parameters from your host page URL after passing them to the Office Online iframe:
>
> wdPreviousSession
> wdPreviousCorrelation
> Other wd* parameters must not be removed from the host page URL.

The key here is that you may not be using the HTML 5 API to do replaceState.